# Second Function on MatPlotlib is Not Fully Displayed

Tags: matplotlib

I would like to get the red function to fully appear. I have tried

```
plt.tight_layout
plt.gcf()
```

This is the code I have for it so far

```
plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
plt.plot(x, ppf(x,1))
plt.plot(x,ppf(x,2))
plt.xlabel("Coconuts")
plt.ylabel("Fish")
plt.xlim(0,20)
plt.ylim(0,20)
plt.margins(y=.1, x=.1)
plt.tight_layout
plt.gcf()
plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7JUu.png)

How should I go about fixing this issue?

This is PPF:

```
cmax =1000
x = np.linspace(0.1,10, 400)
def ppf(x,Ax):
    return np.sqrt(100-(x**2/Ax))
```

Comment: Noone knows what `ppf(x,1)` is. Please read [mcve].

Comment: Sorry about that. Added it.

Answer (score 0):

`x` runs from 0.1 to 10 in both (blue and red) cases. If you want to have one of the curves evaluated at values of `x` larger than 10, you need to supply an array which has those values in it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0.1,10, 400)
x2 = np.linspace(0.1,np.sqrt(199.99), 800)

def ppf(x,Ax):
    return np.sqrt(100-(x**2/Ax))

plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
plt.plot(x, ppf(x,1.))
plt.plot(x2, ppf(x2,2.))
plt.xlabel("Coconuts")
plt.ylabel("Fish")
plt.xlim(0,20)
plt.ylim(0,20)
plt.margins(.1)

plt.show()
```

[image]